# Connect Qtimer with a widget

Tags: qt

I want to use a QTimer object to control a LED indictor status. A `QLed` class inherited `QWidget` is created to control the LED indicator. Here below its two major functions relevant:

```
void QLed::setLEDFlashing(bool value)
{
    ledStatus = value; //Boolean value to accept a user-defined LED status
    m_value = ledStatus; //m_value is used in painting LED (with QtSvgRenderer)

    QTimer ledTimer;
    ledTimer.setInterval(300);
    if(!ledTimer.isActive())
    {
        ledTimer.start();
    }

    //Here is the connection between the timer and this (i.e., QLed*) object
    connect(&ledTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(setLEDFlashingTimerHandler()));
}

//I want to use this function to make LED keep flashing
void QLed::setLEDFlashingTimerHandler() 
{
    //qDebug()<<"setLEDFlashingTimerHandler()";
    if (ledStatus)
    {
        m_value = TRUE;
        ledStatus = FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        m_value = FALSE;
        ledStatus =TRUE;
    }
}

//This is to paint the LED widget
void QLed::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing, true);

    //based on m_value, different svg file is loaded
    if(m_value)
        ledShapeAndColor.append(colors[m_onColor]);
    else
        ledShapeAndColor.append(colors[m_offColor]);

    renderer->load(ledShapeAndColor);
    renderer->render(&painter);

    //qDebug()<<"paintEvent m_value="<<m_value;
}
```

In the `mainwindow.ui`, I add a `QLabel` object (named `led`) and promote it to `QLed`, and in the `mainwindow.cpp`:

```
ui->led->setLEDFlashing(TRUE);
```

The above codes cannot result in a flashing LED indicator. Actually, the connection between `ledTimer` and `setLEDFlashingTimerHandler` does NOT take effect for some reason, and `m_value` is not updated in `paintEvent`. Anyone can help debug my codes? Thanks!

Edits:

I have solved the connection issue by using `QTimer *ledTimer` in stead of `QTimer ledTimer`. But the painting still not works as expected, since `m_value` is not updated in that function or the function is only invoked for the very first time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function `QLed::setLEDFlashing`, you create a local instance of `QTimer` which will be destroyed at the end of your function.

You should declare your `QTimer` as an attribute of your class or use a inner timer with [QObject::startTimer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#startTimer)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That is indeed the reason for the failed connection. I have corrected this by creating a pointer to QTimer. Then the connection works, but the painting still cannot be dynamically updated. I have updated my post by providing the painting function. Could you please check the my code again?

Comment: Call `update()`  in `QLed::setLEDFlashingTimerHandler() `. If you use a pointer, a new timer will be started each `setLEDFlashing` is called. It could create weird behavior (the slot will be called more otfen) and memory leak...